# Existe alguma função em R que possa converter datas?

Tags: r

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Boa tarde,

Sou novata na linguagem R, e preciso de uma pequena ajuda. 
Gostaria de saber se existe alguma função que altera a data do timestamp, era pra ser hora e data, só que o banco de dados me disponibilizou da forma que está na imagem. Andei procurando algumas funções de dada pra R, mas nada se aplica na situação que está os dados que está disponibilizado.
Obrigada

Comment: `as.Date(as.POSIXct(timestamp, origin="1970-01-01"))`

Comment: no momento desse comentário o timespamp do unix é 1525806060 (~ 1.5e9). Qual é a época (o valor do zero, o do unix é 1970-01-01) para esse timestamp maior que 1e12? cara de erro nos dados.

Comment: Então, são dados bem recentes, não tem menos 3 meses esses dados, são dados de um sensor, que captura a temperatura de 5 em 5 segundos

Comment: Um `dput(head(dados))` ajudaria

Answer (score 2):

Chutando sobre dados de um sensor que eu não conheço.

Os dados podem fazer algum sentido se: 1. O timestamp está registrando em milisegundos; 2. Eles mostram o tempo necessário para medir n samples.

Para obter o tempo do timestamp

```
as.POSIXct(1.523365e12/1000, origin="1970-01-01")
[1] "2018-04-10 09:56:40 BRT"
```

Olhe a diferença entre o terceiro e o primeiro timespamp.

```
(1.523372e12 - 1.523365e12)/1000/5 = 1400
```

Que é próximo dos (698 + 697 = 1395) samples entre as coletas. Talvez se o timestamp tivesse uma casa decimal a mais, teria um valor mais exato.
Mas pra confirmar isso, você vai precisar do manual do sensor.